# Some aspects of Visual Basic App not Showing

Tags: vb.net

So as the title suggests I have a visual basic app that isnt showing some of the text boxes I added. The thing is, it shows for some people but not for others. I have had them close/reopen app just in case they were working with an older version.

To give a run down of things ive checked -

All things are set to visible. 
The dates on published version matches file modified date.

Anything else I might need to check? This is quite bizarre and I am not entirely sure why this would occur.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this got down voted, this is actually a bazaar instance

Comment: Is there a blank space where the text boxes should be? Is it possible the user's display settings have pushed the controls off the viewable area of the form? I've seen that happen when the windows display font size is 125% or higher and controls are just placed on a form instead of being docked.

Comment: I guess I need to know how to dock controls then....